# Android tablet app optimisation tips in google console

Tags: android

I get the following optimisation tips in google console, they are :

1. Your layout should make use of the available space on tablets.
2. Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets.

I am not able to solve this 2 things. Can any one help me to solve this problems?

Comment: Are this tips based on manifest file of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the contents of your apk.

## 1. "Your layout should make use of the available space on tablets."

- Start with dimens.xml in your values folder. If you assign textSize = 12 in a normal layout, try using textSize = 15 in the values-sw720dp/dimens.xml folder.
  On your normal layout you'd go like textSize = "@dimen/textsize".
- Another option would be using fragments e.g with a list of items on the left and details of a selected item on the right.

## 2. "Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets"

- Self explanatory? Can't you come up with a feature in your app that may not be available for tablets?

Optimization tips are not compulsory. You may choose to ignore them if you know what you're doing.

Comment: i have used this tag <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> in manifest file ...is this tag causing to display "Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets"

Comment: That could be it. Tablets don't have SIM cards for making phone calls.